# Setting rounded corners in IE8 on <hr> tag with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, rounded-corners

I am experiencing issues with the `border-radius` CSS attribute on IE8. On Safari, Chrome, FF and IE9 this attribute works as expected. However, on IE8 it does not.

I have read some posts and comments about implementing the jQuery Corner plugin, which I have had limited success with. I am unsure whether the issue is with attempting to apply it to a `<hr>`.

Is there a way to achieve the rounded corner affect in CSS alone, without having to use the jQuery Corner plugin?

[image]

My markup:

```
<span id="title_divider"><hr /></span>
```

My CSS:

```
    #title_divider {
        position: absolute;
        width: 49px;
        left: 472px;
        top: 64px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    #title_divider hr {
        height: 10px;
        background-color: #000000;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 7px;
        height: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: I just wouldn't do it, all of these just create so much script overhead that the cool factor of having rounded corners for IE8 isn't worth it (just slows down performance)

Comment: Does it have to be an `<hr />` tag? Or can you swap it out for a `SPAN`? This is much easier to make LOOK like an `HR` than you might think - and which should support rounded corners in all major browsers. If you can use a `SPAN`, let me know and I'll give you a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [`css3pie.com`](http://css3pie.com) it fix issues in all low version which don't support border radius.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** there is.

Take a look at [css3pie here](http://css3pie.com/).

All you need to do is include the file on your server and then point to it in your css like this:

```
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

Comment: Please note, that PIE add overhead of 10ms for each rounded corner on your page.

Comment: @PavelPodlipensky I found an answer to another question that may help the OP : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760044/css3-pie-rounded-corners-slow-down-ie9-even-though-it-supports-them-natively

Comment: @Sam Is it possible to only include that file when required to reduce overhead?